# Find values in ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, range

A hotel provides information about it's rooms using codes like 0103031206100002. Explanation of code: 2 first symbols - is a count of adults (01), next 2 symbols - count of children (03). Remaining 12 symbols we can separate on 3 parts with 4 symbols in each: 0312, 0610, 0002. Which means that room can accommodate one child at age from 3 to 12 years old, plus one child at 6-10 years old and also 0-2 years old one.
That information we store in **Room** table containing other fields also (code, man count, price etc.), but I will show only the needed ones:

| Id | Code | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0103031206100002 | 125 |
| 2 | 0103000600060006 | 120 |
| 3 | 010200020003 | 100 |
| 4 | 01010002 | 38 |

There are about 10k rows in this table.

**First question**: can we execute a query to get the required number of children from the Code field? I didn't find such a way so it was decided to create another table, **ChildAccommodation**:

| Id | Code | ChMinAge | ChMaxAge | RangeNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0103031206100002 | 3 | 12 | 1 |
| 2 | 0103031206100002 | 6 | 10 | 2 |
| 3 | 0103031206100002 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 0103000600060006 | 0 | 6 | 1 |
| 5 | 0103000600060006 | 0 | 6 | 2 |
| 6 | 0103000600060006 | 0 | 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 01010002 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 8 | 01010003 | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| 9 | 01010004 | 0 | 4 | 1 |
| 10 | 010200020003 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 11 | 010200020003 | 0 | 3 | 2 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

here we store more detailed info about ranges according to Code from Room table.

To find a room, we receive the number and ages of children. For example: 3 children aged 2, 5 and 7 years. It should be noted that there can be from 1 to 5 children. As a result, we need to show a row from the Room table, containing Price: a room where all the children can be accommodated.

Let's look at the requirements using code 0103031206100002 as an example:
If we're looking for 2 children aged <=2 years, then the result should be empty, since there is only one range from 0 to 2 years.
For a 7 year old child, both ranges 3-12 and 6-10 are suitable. But the catch here is that if we return the range 3-12 for a 7-years-old, then the 5-years-old will be left out: neither 0-2 nor 6-10 will not suit him anymore. We should get:

- the range 6-10 for a 7-year-old
- then the range 3-12 will be suitable for a 5-year-old
- and the range 0-2 for a 2-years-old

in which case all the children will be accommodated.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/nC-MtSE1) you can find the example of the table with the data.

**And the second, main question**: what script/request can help to know if we have suitable room to have all the children accommodated in separate ranges?

I've tried many options as recursive CTE, relational division etc, but still can't find the solution.

For example, here is the one of numerous scripts. We search for 2, 6 and 6 years old children:

```sql
declare @childs table (Id int primary key, Age int);

INSERT INTO @childs (Id, Age)
VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (2, 6),
    (3, 6);

select *
from @childs as c
    cross apply (select count(*) from @childs) as cc(cnt)
inner join ChildAccommodation as ca
    on c.Age between ca.ChMinAge and ca.ChMaxAge
        AND SUBSTRING(ca.Code,3, 2) = cc.cnt
```

As result, I get the following table:

| Id | Age | cnt | Id | Code | ChMinAge | ChMaxAge | RangeNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 6 | 3 | 1 | 0103031206100002 | 3 | 12 | 1 |
| 3 | 6 | 3 | 1 | 0103031206100002 | 3 | 12 | 1 |
| 2 | 6 | 3 | 2 | 0103031206100002 | 6 | 10 | 2 |
| 3 | 6 | 3 | 2 | 0103031206100002 | 6 | 10 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 0103031206100002 | 0 | 2 | 3 |

and cannot take exactly 3 ranges, because both ranges 3-12 and 6-10 are suitable for each of 6-years old children. Groupping by Code and counting of Ages/Ids/Ranges will give a wrong result because of duplicates.

Comment: The definition of the `room` is missing? (or should I re-read the question?)

Comment: The 5-year old only fits in 1 region (3-12) so you have to start with that child, and after that the 7-year old which fits in two region, but 3-12 is already occupied, so pick 6-10.

Comment: Room - is the first table shown in the topic
The main task is to obtain an sql script or request that will correctly distribute children among ranges

Comment: Note that sample data values like 1, 2 and 3 are so much easier to get than 0103031206100002 and similar. Make it easy to help you.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (MS SQL Server?)

Comment: @jarlh DbFiddle is for MSSQL, so ... 

Comment: I tried, but not enough time.... (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/a671vFMi for what i started with , but ....mind is elsewhere...)

Comment: Firstly you should ask 2 questions as two separate questions... secondly your question would be much clearer if it had less text and more data i.e. show the sample data, the desired results, explain (simply) the logic and show your attempt. If you applied that to your 2 questions I think you would probably get answers.

Comment: Yes, @jarlh,  MS SQL. I understand that simple values are easier to get.. May be in this case simple parts are ranges, not Code itself )

Comment: Thank you @Luuk. I'm starting to think that maybe the ChildAccommodation table isn't needed at all.

Comment: Thank you, @DaleK. I will try to explain it more simply in future comment.

Comment: Ideally you would store your data normalised in the first place rather than combining a bunch of information into a single column - you are seeing the issues this causes.

Comment: @Step what's the max room capacity?

Comment: @DaleK, I'm receiving the complete Code in result of API request. And you're right, I wouldn't keep that data in one field like that..

Comment: @Marko, the max capacity is 10 Adults and 5 Childs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your second question, what you can do is generate all possible permutations of child -> room slots.

For example:

```
// 1st permutation
Child #1 -> Room slot #1
Child #2 -> Room slot #2
Child #3 -> Room slot #3

// 2nd permutation
Child #1 -> Room slot #1
Child #3 -> Room slot #2
Child #2 -> Room slot #3

// 3rd permutation
Child #2 -> Room slot #1
Child #1 -> Room slot #2
Child #3 -> Room slot #3

// etc.
```

After you generated all permutations check if each `Child -> Room slot` assignment satisfies the age restrictions for that particular room slot.

Valid permutations are the ones for which all assignments satisfy the condition, therefore, the room related to that permutation is suitable.

You can check the code [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xc6LTYzM).

Comment: Please ensure your answer is standalone i.e. contains the code inline I'm addition to any fiddles

Comment: Looks amazing, Marco. Thank you!
I'll check it later and be sure to tell you.

Comment: I've only tried it on 2 and 3 kids so far, and this query is producing the best results of any I've tried so far.

Comment: Marco, it works! ) This is some kind of magic )
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this. This code isn't optimized for prettiness or being succinct, but I think it works.

This only addresses your first question. I.e this unpacks the coded strings and gives you basically relational data to mess with. The other question should probably be its own question, but if someone wants to take this code and use it to complete the other question, by all means, go for it.

Run your baseline data through a recursive CTE which chomps off 4-character segments of the code until there aren't any more.

Then, split the resulting 4-char codes on the left and right two characters for the age ranges

```
-- Populate example data
drop table if exists #Room
create table #Room
(
    RoomId int not null,
    Code varchar(50) not null,
    Price float not null
)

insert into #Room
values
    (1,'0103031206100002',  125),
    (2,'0103000600060006',  120),
    (3,'010200020003',  100),
    (4,'01010002',  38)

-- Split out the known parts, and have the Remainder field be everything after those first two pieces are chomped off
drop table if exists #Base
select 
    RoomId,
    Code,
    Price,
    NumAdults = substring(Code, 1, 2),
    NumChildren = substring(Code, 3, 2),
    Remainder = substring(Code, 5, len(Code))
into #Base
from #Room

-- Recursively chomp out 4 character slices of Remainder util there are none left
;with cte as
(
    select 
        RoomId,
        Code,
        Price,
        NumAdults,
        NumChildren,
        SubCode = convert(varchar(50), iif(len(Remainder) >= 4, left(Remainder, 4), null)),
        Remainder = convert(varchar(50), stuff(Remainder, 1, 4, '')),
        RangeNum = 1
    from #Base
    union all
    select 
        b.RoomId,
        b.Code,
        b.Price,
        b.NumAdults,
        b.NumChildren,
        SubCode = convert(varchar(50), iif(len(c.Remainder) >= 4, left(c.Remainder, 4), null)),
        Remainder = convert(varchar(50), stuff(c.Remainder, 1, 4, '')),
        RangeNum = c.RangeNum + 1
    from #Base b
    inner join cte c
        on b.RoomId = c.RoomId
    where len(c.Remainder) >= 4
)
-- Results and beautification
select 
    RoomId,
    Code,
    Price,
    NumAdults = try_convert(int, NumAdults),
    NumChildren = try_convert(int, NumChildren),
    SubCode,
    ChildMinAge = try_convert(int, left(SubCode, 2)),
    ChildMaxAge = try_convert(int, right(SubCode, 2)),
    RangeNum
from cte
order by RoomId, RangeNum
```

Comment: Thank you, Xedni. Your code works perfect.
But my first question was, do I really need the ChildAccommodation table (cte in your case)? Is it make sence or is it better to directly use the Code field from the Room table to search the ranges? Anyway, I'm looking for answer in both ways, and in case of using that additional table, your code will help.